# Django Initialize Form current user with CreateView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-generic-views

I wanto to display the current user in the form before submitting.

**views.py**

```
class PostEncabezadoReporte(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

    form_class = PostEncabezadoReporteForm
    template_name = "crear_reporte.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        object = form.save(commit=False)
        object.user = self.request.user
        object.startweek, object.endweek = self.weekdatetimeconverter(
            object.semana)
        object.folio = self.getfolio(
            object.user, object.semana, object.tipo_reporte)

        self.validar_unico = self.reporte_unico(
            object.user, object.semana, object.cliente)

        if self.validar_unico == 0:
            object.save()
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

        return super(PostEncabezadoReporte, self).form_valid(form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostEncabezadoReporteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = EncabezadoReporte
        fields = ('user', 'tipo_reporte', 'tipo_gasto', 'cliente',
                  'semana', 'folio')
        widgets = {'semana': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'week'}),
                   }
```

I alreayd tried to override the init in the form and is not working, I can select the user in the field but I want it to be displayed at init.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to override the init in the form but I had a problem, I was missing a line after the super, this is an example of another form init that I did:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.carro = kwargs.pop('encabezado')
        super(AgregarGastoReporte, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['encabezado'].initial = self.carro
```